# Show model errors in client side without postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation, service-layer

I have created a form using asp.net mvc with service layer to validate business logic without model validation using Data Annotations.

This is my code in the service class for validation

```
public class TutorService : ITutorService       
{
    private ModelStateDictionary modelstate;
    private ITutorRepository repository;

    public TutorService(ModelStateDictionary modelstate, ITutorRepository repository)
    {
        this.modelstate = modelstate;
        this.repository = repository;

    }

    //Validation Logic
    protected bool Validate(Tutor tutor)
    {

        if (tutor.FirstName==null)
            modelstate.AddModelError("FirstName", "First Name is required.");

        if (tutor.LastName == null)
            modelstate.AddModelError("LastName", "Last Name is required.");

        return modelstate.IsValid;
    }

    public bool CreateTutor(Tutor tutor)
    {
        if (Validate(tutor))
        {
            try
            {
                repository.CreateTutor(tutor);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tutor> ListTutors()
    {
        return repository.ListTutors();
    }
}

public interface ITutorService
{
    bool CreateTutor(Tutor productToCreate);
    IEnumerable<Tutor> ListTutors();
}
```

this method use for validate the model. In this mechanism client side validation does not work. When click the submit button it post back and display error messages. But I want to display error messages without post backing. I have already added

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

to BundleConfig.cs and

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

to Web.config file.

This Is Tutor Create View :

```
@model MvcApplication7.Models.DB.Tutor

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

 <h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Tutor</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address2)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address3)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address3)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address3)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tel1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tel1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tel1)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tel2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tel2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tel2)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EMail)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EMail)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EMail)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsConfirmed)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsConfirmed)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsConfirmed)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Tutor Class :

```
 public partial class Tutor
{
    public Tutor()
    {
        this.Examinations = new HashSet<Examination>();
    }

    public decimal TutorID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Tel1 { get; set; }
    public string Tel2 { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsConfirmed { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Examination> Examinations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is your property data annonation, you are validating using service.

Comment: Please show `Tutor` class

Comment: I don't use any data annotation attribute to validate inside model. Tutor class is plain class generated by EF and it contains only FirstName, LastName and some other properties without data annotation.

Comment: Can you post your view ?

Comment: Post your tutor class code

Comment: I posted my view and Tutor class

Comment: Decorate your `FirstName` and `LastName` properties in Tutor class with `[Required]` attribute and give it a try.

Comment: When I add [Required] annotation to that attributes it will flush out when edmx model change and I want to add model errors separately. In my approach successfully display error messages in error labels but it is postbacking. It is the problem.

Comment: I did this program using this tutorial. this is the approach how im doing this program. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs But in this approach client side validation does not working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe help

> Install-Package jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive

Comment: added Attribute  tutor.FirstName [Remote("Action", "Controller")] ?

Comment: just below the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `MetadataType` data annotation to generate the second class for Tutor.

Basically EF generates `Tutor` as a partial class and you can create another class within the same namespace with data annotations.

Here is what it takes to look like

```
namespace MVCApplication
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TutorMetaData))]//<- Just adding this class level attribute does the job for us.
    public partial class Tutor
    {
        public Tutor()
        {
            this.Examinations = new HashSet<Examination>();
        }

        public decimal TutorID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }
        public string Tel1 { get; set; }
        public string Tel2 { get; set; }
        public string EMail { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsConfirmed { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Examination> Examinations { get; set; }
    }

    public class TutorMetaData
    {
        public Tutor()
        {
            this.Examinations = new HashSet<Examination>();
        }

        public decimal TutorID { get; set; }
        [Required] //<-- use as many annotations as you like
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required] //<-- use as many annotations as you like
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }
        public string Tel1 { get; set; }
        public string Tel2 { get; set; }
        public string EMail { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsConfirmed { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Examination> Examinations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In some cases one attributes uses more than one view with more than one error message to same annotation (for example : Create view display one error message and Edit view display another error message to same annotation) . I think this approach is not the best. And [MetadataType(typeof(TutorMetaData))] code also flushing out when edmx change.

Answer (score 0):

change `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));`
to

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```